# C#.Net ASP.Net Data Controls

Tags: c#, controls, asp.net-2.0

Could anybody explain what does this contain:

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the first column of the first row of the first table. If you are asking for something else please be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is referring to the first column in the first DataRow from the first DataTable in a DataSet.